# Rails 7 using custom js in specific pages

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-7, import-maps

Having adapted the hotwire mechanism for rails 7, problems arise for custom JS that are dependency-less.  in this case, a JS that is not mapped to a given source.

Added to `importmap.rb`:

```
pin_all_from "app/javascript/plugin", under: "plugin"
```

which does render

```
    <script type="importmap" data-turbo-track="reload">{
  "imports": {
    "application": "/assets/application-37f365cbecf1fa2810a8303f4b6571676fa1f9c56c248528bc14ddb857531b95.js",
    "@hotwired/turbo-rails": "/assets/turbo.min-e5023178542f05fc063cd1dc5865457259cc01f3fba76a28454060d33de6f429.js",
    "@hotwired/stimulus": "/assets/stimulus.min-900648768bd96f3faeba359cf33c1bd01ca424ca4d2d05f36a5d8345112ae93c.js",
    "@hotwired/stimulus-loading": "/assets/stimulus-loading-1fc59770fb1654500044afd3f5f6d7d00800e5be36746d55b94a2963a7a228aa.js",
    "controllers/application": "/assets/controllers/application-368d98631bccbf2349e0d4f8269afb3fe9625118341966de054759d96ea86c7e.js",
    "controllers/hello_controller": "/assets/controllers/hello_controller-549135e8e7c683a538c3d6d517339ba470fcfb79d62f738a0a089ba41851a554.js",
    "controllers": "/assets/controllers/index-2db729dddcc5b979110e98de4b6720f83f91a123172e87281d5a58410fc43806.js",
    "plugin/auto-complete": "/assets/plugin/auto-complete-813c8033519c4886434d3f867f4159971e0d46aca097d6706580f5042f78d4ec.js"
  }
```

Also note that I made the mistake of running `./bin/rails javascript:install:esbuild`
which leads to unnecessary pollution of the header and do not know how to un-do this ([indictions not provided with the gem](https://github.com/rails/jsbundling-rails))

```
<script type="esms-options">{"nonce":null}</script>
<script src="/assets/es-module-shims.min-b8099fffdbd758070d4801321d43b389c5b6174a50782f9f4cb57061533b7ac2.js" async="async" data-turbo-track="reload"></script>
```

could this be a factor in impeding the eventual loading of the script?

Apparently, a declaration is required to have it load: `<%= javascript_import_module_tag "plugin" %>`.  While the preference is to load it on the action that requires it, this was added to the application.html.erb file.

To no avail.
The script runs only if the raw script is included in the action's view.

Is there a more succinct manner to load such a script as necessary?

**Update**

The suggestion provided by @alex appears in the right direction, however, a greater issue exists for the browser, with a fresh application creation, pushing the situation into a different question.
[FF version required](https://caniuse.com/import-maps) an ImportMap enabling under `about:config` which then rendered the same situation as Chrome:
[image: FF console]

[image: module spec]
The same error arises when substituting the `pin_all_from` command with
`pin("plugin/auto-complete")`

Chrome:
[image: chrome console]

Thus the building tool is working in an unexpected manner under `pin_all_from` and `pin` with

```
<% content_for :head do %>
  <%= javascript_import_module_tag "plugin/autocomplete" %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: have you been able to fix this error?

Comment: Alas, not in a railsy way.  Fortunately the maximum array of objects is around 9000 and can be conveniently put into cache and be the size of a moderately heavy image.  Which then gets stuffed into a partial, itself cached.  Which turns out to be more reliable speed-wise and generally faster than round-tripping to the server after each character typed.

Answer (score 0):

As a fix you can use path directly created by pin_all - one you can see in page source code.

In your case - `/assets/plugin/auto-complete`